# How to get access to express routes of a docker container from another docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, microservices

I am working on a microservice with about 5 services. Each service is in its own container-obviously different ip address. Each service has its own database. Each works fine independently. I am using docker-compose to bring up the services which connects them together in the same network.

I am having a challenge trying to access routes of one container from another container e.g app.use('/api/auth', routes.auth); is in usermanagement service and app.use('/api/tasks', routes.tasks); is in the tasks service. How do I access the the tasks routes from the usermanagement service? Simply put, I want to get data from the tasks service from the usermanagement.

I have tried [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/tree/v0.21.0#options) but I with no success so far.

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

You have create one network in docker
While running containers attache the network
Create network

```
docker network create network
```

You are running two containers 
Container1 3000 port

```
docker run -d --name Container1 --net network -p 3000:3000 yourimage
```

Container2 4000 port

```
docker run -d --name Container2 --net network -p 4000:4000 yourimage
```

```
You can access container1 routes in containers 2 like 
curl container1:3000/

Same like vice Versa you call another containers like that
```

Comment: I am using docker-compose and yes I have them in one network. The challenge was calling a route from another e.g [router.get('/tasks', handle.tasks);] route in tasks from usermanagement container.

Comment: Can explain little bit more I am not understanding what you are trying to say

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Hope its a bit more clearer.

Comment: Try with network_mode: "host" to containers and remove all network attachments. When you run the docker compose it will create bridge network so now attach host network to conntainers it will solve your issue

Comment: The network works fine .. my trouble is getting data from the tasks server. How do I include tasks routes in the usermanagement server?

Comment: You can't include task routes into user management server , you said when you run the sever in local those are working fine ( iam assuming both management and tasks  are running in different project ) how that is worked ?